# Using function output is input to another function

Tags: python

I have a function that creates a dictionary say

```
def myfunction (x,y):
    dictionary = dict(zip(x, y))
    return
```

i then want to use this dictionary in a new function - what is the syntax to get the dictionary as an arguement for the new function (how do i fix the code below- ie the def newfunction )

```
def newfunction(newinput, myfunction()):
    do something
    return
```

Comment: Do you want it as a default argument? Or are you trying to call `newfunction`? You can't define and call `newfunction` at once like that. You also haven't passed any arguments to `myfunction`, so I'm unclear on what you're expecting it to do. If you don't understand defining or calling functions at all, please talk to a tutor/teacher/professor; it's what they're paid for, and you're not going to get anywhere asking Stack Overflow for stuff this basic.

Comment: thanks - but i am not a student - self teaching python - based on tyring to code questions found on line - find that, at least for me this is a good way of learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the function in the normal way, say,

```
def newfunction(newinput, anDict):
    do something
    return something
```

And when you call the `newfunction`, pass the `myfunction` as a parameter like this:

```
res = newfunction(newinput, myfunction)
```

Moreover, you have to modify your `myfunction` to return the dictionary you generate:

```
def myfunction (x, y):
    return dict(zip(x, y))
```

Comment: How is `res` supposed to return anything from `myfunction`, there's no arguments, so what good is it? It seems completely useless.

Comment: `res` is surely useless, i just want to show a invoking process.

Comment: Wasn't the question on how to call and return the value of a function while calling another?

Answer (score 0):

Return the dictionary.

```
def myfunction (x,y):
    dictionary = dict(zip(x, y))
    return dictionary
```

If you want a return value from a function, you place it on the `return` line. If you want multiple return values, separate them with a comma and the return value will be a tuple containing the values.